# How do I make my submit button disappear onclick?

Tags: javascript, button

How do I make button disappear onclick? Here is my javascript

```js
$(document).on('click', '.submit', function(){
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
      if(confirm("Kindly check all values to ensure no error before clicking ok"))
      {
        $.ajax({
          url:"plan.php",
          method:"POST",
          data:{id:id},
          success:function(data)
          {
            $('#alert_message').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
            $('#user_data').DataTable().destroy();
            fetch_data();
          }
        })
      }  
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I want to know where to insert the function to make the button disappear after clicking it. I am new to javascript and only miraculously got this to work.

Comment: `$(this).remove()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `this` to access the button clicked. and [`remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) to make it disappear.Use `hide()` if you don't want to permanently disappear button.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#submit', function(){
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
      $(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: hi thank you very much for replying. The button reappears after a while again when I refresh

Comment: @Ahmedtijani Umar refreshing the page reloads the initial html page